What's wrong with my campy derailleur?
I'm trying to tune my campy chroma 10 speed but it wont shift to either the 2 highest gears or 2 lowest gears. Could it be that the drivetrain is bent? Is this due to a bad hanger? 

Can you post a photo that shows how the cable is connected to the derailleur? From this perspective it looks wrong but difficult to see.

Hanger is without doubt bent.
You must either replace it or have it properly aligned.
That should improve things to the point that either only minor adjustment is required or further diagnosis is possible.

The bike in picture is tilted to right. If you rotate the photo so that the handlebar and rear hub are horizontal, the hanger looks quite straight but the cabinets in the background are now horribly crooked.

@ojs when I follow the line of the cogs to the RD cage, the cage definitely looks bent. With this era of derailleur, that’s not supposed to happen.

@WeiwenNg which era of derailleur is it? Also, is it the cage or hanger that is bent?

@ojs OP said it was a 10s derailleur. With Shimano 11s, I think sometimes the cage looks a bit bent even if the hangar is straight - this may carry over to C11 derailleurs or it may not. If the hangar were bent, then the cage will look bent. The RD cage looks at about a right angle to the RD body, so I assume the cage is not bent - also, I don't think we usually see a cage bent but not the hangar.

@WeiwenNg I think at this point we can agree that we are looking at different pictures.

Stop bickering, you two. The photograph is perfectly good enough to judge the hanger is suspect. The cable routing is fine. It sounds like the limit screws have been mis-set but the hanger has to be proven good before this is corrected.
